# Divine punishments of opressing tribes?? All of them even kids?

Tags: belief, punishment, children

Well, we have a lot of stories in holy Qur'an about tribes of different prophets who were misguided and oppressor, finally when disappointed of their guidance God sends down a punishment and everyone dies except believers. (E.g. Prophet Noah's tribe)

It doesn't explain but I assume the whole tribe is punished, right? Is that also the case for the kids of the tribe? If yes, how can we explain this?

Comment: When famine strikes African countries children suffer too. There is this belief that the affect of parents misdeeds and food they have given to there children have affect on them. So children could be affected by it, but this doesn't mean they'd be doomed to hell in the Hereafter.

Comment: [Isn't God responsible for those killed in accidents?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16853/isnt-god-responsible-for-those-killed-in-accidents)

Comment: @BleedingFingers  A false believe that has nothing to do with Islam.

Comment: Theer are many different and possible explanations one of them might be concluded when reading the story of Musa and al-Khidra ([18:60-80](https://legacy.quran.com/18/60-80)).

Answer (score 2):

Divine punishment can be indiscriminate, if any of them were innocent they will be saved in the afterlife i recently read an essay which quoted some relevant passages i will copy them here as a reminder.

> Surah Anfal 8:25
>
> And fear the Fitnah (affliction and trial) which affects not in
> particular (only) those of you who do wrong (but it may afflict all
> the good and the bad people), and know that Allâh is Severe in
> punishment.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ عُثْمَانَ، أَخْبَرَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ،
> أَخْبَرَنَا يُونُسُ، عَنِ الزُّهْرِيِّ، أَخْبَرَنِي حَمْزَةُ بْنُ
> عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عُمَرَ، أَنَّهُ سَمِعَ ابْنَ عُمَرَ ـ رضى الله
> عنهما ـ يَقُولُ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ إِذَا
> أَنْزَلَ اللَّهُ بِقَوْمٍ عَذَابًا، أَصَابَ الْعَذَابُ مَنْ كَانَ
> فِيهِمْ، ثُمَّ بُعِثُوا عَلَى أَعْمَالِهِمْ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> Narrated Ibn `Umar: Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "If Allah sends
> punishment upon a nation then it befalls upon the whole population
> indiscriminately and then they will be resurrected (and judged)
> according to their deeds. "
>
> Sahih al-Bukhari 7108 https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7108
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ الصَّبَّاحِ، حَدَّثَنَا إِسْمَاعِيلُ بْنُ
> زَكَرِيَّاءَ، عَنْ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ سُوقَةَ، عَنْ نَافِعِ بْنِ جُبَيْرِ
> بْنِ مُطْعِمٍ، قَالَ حَدَّثَتْنِي عَائِشَةُ ـ رضى الله عنها ـ قَالَتْ
> قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ يَغْزُو جَيْشٌ
> الْكَعْبَةَ، فَإِذَا كَانُوا بِبَيْدَاءَ مِنَ الأَرْضِ يُخْسَفُ
> بِأَوَّلِهِمْ وَآخِرِهِمْ ‏"‏‏.‏ قَالَتْ قُلْتُ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ
> كَيْفَ يُخْسَفُ بِأَوَّلِهِمْ وَآخِرِهِمْ، وَفِيهِمْ أَسْوَاقُهُمْ
> وَمَنْ لَيْسَ مِنْهُمْ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ يُخْسَفُ بِأَوَّلِهِمْ
> وَآخِرِهِمْ، ثُمَّ يُبْعَثُونَ عَلَى نِيَّاتِهِمْ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> Narrated `Aisha: Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "An army will invade the Ka`ba and when the invaders reach Al-Baida', all the ground will sink
> and swallow the whole army." I said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! How
> will they sink into the ground while amongst them will be their
> markets (the people who worked in business and not invaders) and the
> people not belonging to them?" The Prophet (ﷺ) replied, "all of those
> people will sink but they will be resurrected and judged according to
> their intentions."
>
> Sahih al-Bukhari 2118 https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2118