# Isn't God responsible for those killed in accidents?

Tags: allah, punishment

God says the murder of one person is murder of whole humanity. And the murderer should be sentenced to death.

Who is then responsible for other kind of deaths e.g. tsunami, earth quake, storms weather and all other kind of deaths in which another person is not responsible by any means.

A person will be punished by death if he kills an innocent child, won't God be responsible if He kills that child in an earthquake?

Comment: Yes and that is why it is Allah who has control over our death.

Comment: What god knows we don't know If he kills an innocent child It is his wish He is the one who created him. Second thing he is created so he knows how to take it back without making feel of death(means without pain) as the person who die in the islamic battle (martyrs) he will feel like a ant bite. Third He will directly send those people to jannah (paradise) and they will be considered as martyr. what else you want your 60 years of life is finished making a forever life(millions of thousands year)  good and nice.

Comment: @LifeH2O and how is that different from someone who dies of old age? In the end the person is dead, I am not sure what exactly are you suggesting.

Comment: @mosaad We have no control over age and no one is punished for that. But when someone kills another, severe punishment is given to hold justice. To make sure that people don't just kill each other.

Comment: @mosaad "In the end the person is dead" they way how one dies matter. You won't forgive one who kills children brutally but you won't have any issue with the one who kills the killers.

Comment: @LifeH2O like we have no control over age we also have no control over tsunamis, eathquakes etc...  however I don't still understand what exactly are you trying to say

Comment: @mosaad I am trying to say that one should be able to ask 'God' why he killed someone brutally but didn't allow a man to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

The relationship is that of Creator(Master) and slave, the Creator has set the rules for the creation. They are not applicable to the Creator, He may do what He wills.
For us, we cannot understand the wisdom behind these events however one thing for sure is that they are a test for us.

Answer (score 2):

In Islam, you cannot take innocent human life not because there is anything sacred about it, but rather because Allah forbids humans from doing so.

> قُلْ تَعَالَوْا أَتْلُ مَا حَرَّمَ رَبُّكُمْ عَلَيْكُمْ ۖ أَلَّا تُشْرِكُوا بِهِ شَيْئًا ۖ وَبِالْوَالِدَيْنِ إِحْسَانًا ۖ وَلَا تَقْتُلُوا أَوْلَادَكُم مِّنْ إِمْلَاقٍ ۖ نَّحْنُ نَرْزُقُكُمْ وَإِيَّاهُمْ ۖ وَلَا تَقْرَبُوا الْفَوَاحِشَ مَا ظَهَرَ مِنْهَا وَمَا بَطَنَ ۖ وَلَا تَقْتُلُوا النَّفْسَ الَّتِي حَرَّمَ اللَّهُ إِلَّا بِالْحَقِّ ۚ ذَٰلِكُمْ وَصَّاكُم بِهِ لَعَلَّكُمْ تَعْقِلُونَ - 6:151
>
> Say, "Come, I will recite what your Lord has prohibited to you. [He commands] that you not associate anything with Him, and to parents, good treatment, and do not kill your children out of poverty; We will provide for you and them. And do not approach immoralities - what is apparent of them and what is concealed. **And do not kill the soul which Allah has forbidden [to be killed] except by [legal] right**. This has He instructed you that you may use reason."

It does not say 'do not kill the sacred soul'. It says 'do not kill the soul Allah forbid to be killed'. So, the reasons humans can't kill someone innocent is because Allah did not allow them to. The reason Allah can do it is because he has or can have no such forbiddance upon him. Additionally, he owns everyone's soul, body, and mind, and he has every right to take back what is rightfully his.

Comment: I think it is still important to point out that there can be no other reasons not to kill someone other than that their soul is sacred or that Allah forbid it. The example I gave with Xyz I think shows that. I am not saying that non-muslims are content with murder. But, rather that the reason they don't like murder is because Allah gave everyone a Fitrah. Not because of something from themselves.

Answer (score 1):

In the name of ***Allah***

First of all you should know that *Allah* is the "Creator" of both death and life as
this verse states:

> الَّذِي خَلَقَ الْمَوْتَ وَالْحَيَاةَ لِيَبْلُوَكُمْ أَيُّكُمْ أَحْسَنُ عَمَلًا وَهُوَ الْعَزِيزُ الْغَفُورُ
>     [He] who created death and life to test you [as to] which of you is best in deed - and He is the Exalted in Might, the Forgiving
>   Surat Al-Mulk 67:2

And death is inevitable and every one is going to die:

> كُلُّ نَفْسٍ ذَائِقَةُ الْمَوْتِ وَنَبْلُوكُمْ بِالشَّرِّ وَالْخَيْرِ فِتْنَةً وَإِلَيْنَا تُرْجَعُونَ
>   Every soul will taste death. And We test you with evil and with good as trial; and to Us you will be returned.
>   Surat Al-'Anbyā 21:35

And live has a certain term:

> قُلْ لَا أَمْلِكُ لِنَفْسِي ضَرًّا وَلَا نَفْعًا إِلَّا مَا شَاءَ اللَّهُ لِكُلِّ أُمَّةٍ أَجَلٌ إِذَا جَاءَ أَجَلُهُمْ فَلَا يَسْتَأْخِرُونَ سَاعَةً وَلَا يَسْتَقْدِمُونَ
>   Say, "I possess not for myself any harm or benefit except what Allah should will. For every nation is a [specified] term. When their time has come, then they will not remain behind an hour, nor will they precede [it]."
>   Surat Yūnus 10:49

So it is not our right to ask *Allah* or blame him about his creations or doing as this verse states:

> لَا يُسْأَلُ عَمَّا يَفْعَلُ وَهُمْ يُسْأَلُونَ
>     He is not questioned about what He does, but they will be questioned.
>     Surat Al-'Anbyā 21:23

After all *Allah* is he who created us.

Answer (score 0):

The deaths of those innocent around us is just to remind us that our time on this dunya is very limited and should not be squandered and as such we should be in constant remembrence of Allaah for he is in control of eveything

Answer (score 0):

God gave us all free will as a gift to mankind. Whenever something bad happens it is not because God has willed it; it is because of a mistake of man.

To say that God is in control of all actions is a fallacy otherwise please explain why some of the most God loving people had bad things happening to them.

Comment: you say it is because of a mistake of man. Then what about children who are born with cancer?! Those, according to Islam, are forgiven for their mistakes until they become adults!

Answer (score -1):

We are responsible for that as it is the punishment of our sins, And It is good for children or Innocents as they will directly go to jannah( Heaven) as they are considered as Shaheed but this answer is for believers.

You created a robot. now he will not listen to you but it listen to your enemy and it will do exactly opposite what you wants. what you will do to him.

**Edit**

In ahadith it is stated:

> “Anas May Allah be pleased with him says, “I went into the presence of Aishah May Allah be pleased with our mother whilst someone else was seated with her. The person asked, ‘O Mother of the believers, relate to us regarding earthquakes (as to their cause)’ She turned her face away. I (Anas) asked her, ‘Relate to us regarding earthquakes, O Mother of the believers!’ She said, “O Anas, if I were to inform you thereof, you will live a sorrowful life and you will die in this state of grief and you will be raised on the Day of Judgement whilst this fear is in your heart.” I said, “O Mother, relate to me.” She then said, “When a woman removes her clothes in a house other than her husbands (an indication towards adultery), she tears the veil between her and Allah. When she applies perfume to please a male other than her husband, this will be a source of fire and a blemish for her. When the people then begin to commit adultery, consume alcohol and use musical instruments, Allah becomes enraged in the heavens and orders the Earth to shake them. If they repent and refrain, then it is good for them, otherwise Allah will cause it to fall upon them.” I asked, “Is this their punishment?” She said, “It is rather a mercy, means of blessings and admonishment for the believers, and a punishment, display of anger and torment for the unbelievers.”

Comment: This makes it look like Allah decrees punishment as death.

Comment: @AshwinSingh Please see my edits ans suggest if wrong.

Comment: If I had created that robot, I will know exactly how to make it listen to me and not my enemies. If I deliberately made it to listen to my enemies, why will I do anything? I made it that way.

Comment: @LifeH2O   Its just an example i know what robots are It will not have intelligence its just an another dummy machine whatever you programmed it can only do that but what i am telling you is you have created and programmed it to only listen to you but still he is not listening to you whenever you try to test it it is not doing what you want either it is breaking other robots or doing whatever it wants

Comment: you say it is because of a mistake of man. Then what about children who are born with cancer?! Those, according to Islam, are forgiven for their mistakes until they become adults!